# How to upgrade Visual studio 2013 with update 4 to update 5?

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I have installed VS 2013 with update 4 , now how i can upgrade to Update 5?

Is there any steps to follow for upgrade ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I got it, Open Visual Studio->Tool-->extensions and update--> see updates, then select and click on update.

Answer (score 1):

1) install daemon tools lite 10  from here (if you do not have it)

[https://www.daemon-tools.cc/downloads#page](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=519391)

2) download the update 5 from here

[vs 2013 update 5 download](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=519391)

3) double click on the vs2013 update 5 .iso format file of the step 2 ,click on the .exe and  an installation window will appear